# Tracking number of times web content has been viewed within a page?

Tags: database, web-services, rest, relational-database

I was reading more about Quora's answer rank algorithm, and came across the following feature which I'm trying to reverse engineer:

http://blog.quora.com/Improved-Answer-Ranking-Follow-Up

*"with new answer ranking, we are not focusing solely on the absolute number of upvotes and downvotes; we are also considering the level of attention that an answer has received. For example: **if 20 people see an answer**, and all 20 of them upvote it, that may be a stronger quality signal than if thousands of people see an answer but only 100 upvote it."*

Little background on Quora: It's very similar to Stack Exchange in layout. Someone posts a question, people reply with answers, and the site ranks/displays all the answers in a single page.

Given that all the answers are compiled into a single page, how would Quora keep track of the number of views that each individual answer has gotten?

Potential hypothesis:

1. Each individual answer is stored in a database, together with a
   counter of how many times it has been fetched.
2. When the user first visits the page, only the first few answers are
   fetched from the database and shown on the page. As the user scrolls
   down, more answers are dynamically fetched through additional GET
   requests.
3. Each time a answer is fetched from the database, the database
   counter is incremented, thus tracking the number of times an answer
   has been seen by viewers.

Concerns with this approach:

1. Every single GET request now requires database updates, which will
   significantly worsen database workload.
2. Instead of batch-fetching 10-20 answers as soon the user loads the
   page, the site will instead have to fetch 1-2 answers, every time
   the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. This will worsen
   latencies and user experience, as the user would have to keep
   waiting for additional content to show up.

Are these real concerns that blow up with scale? Or can they be managed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some speculation on how it's done.

**STORING VIEW STATS**

Yes, Quora does need to store views per answer, as is commonly done at scale by app developers. However, you imply they are storing it in the same place as the answer, whereas in practice, they will probably store it separately in a medium that's more optimised for fast writes and less so for reliability (it's okay if you miss a few views due to a server outage; it's less okay if you don't save the user's answer). For example, it could be stored in Redis, which keeps stats in memory and only writes to disk once a minute by default. Or they  could store them in memcached and write their own periodic process to dump results to the main database.

**COUNTING VIEWS**

It's unlikely views would be counted as you describe, ie how many times the data is requested, because a good distributed architecture should be caching that kind of content in the browser and at intermediate points along the way. It's more likely they are tracking views directly in their browser and apps by checking, upon scroll events, if some element has become visible. They could then periodically upload a bulk list of viewed items.

Comment: Thanks for the educated guess. Do you have any links to resources on how to implement **"by checking, upon scroll events, if some element has become visible."** 

My naive REST understanding is that you send data to the client on a GET request, and unless they send you another GET/PUT/POST request, you will not know how the data is consumed. How does a REST interface collect information on **scroll events** and whether **"some element has become visible"**?

Comment: Well, any live scrolling library/tutorial will show how to identify when the user has reached a certain element. Once the client script knows that, it can post that to a "view" API. In the absence of a persistent connection (e.g. websocket), it would be more likely to post in batches rather than every individual view. The actual service for this would simply be something like a /views resource, so client posts to /views. The request would probably include some detail about the user, the client platform, and the viewing context such as a containing web page URL.